# PHP's shorthand equivalent to python's for & in

Tags: php, python

I've currently got the following in Python:

```
[i['itemId'] for i in rc['duplicateItemIdList']]
```

What'd be the necessary way to replicate this in PHP in such **shorthand**, the way it's done in Python?

This obviously could be solved using something such as:

```
foreach($duplicateItemIdList as $id) {
    $this->duplicates[] = $id['itemId'];
}
```

Comment: use a foreach loop

Comment: Show us what are your efforts towards solving this.

Comment: @inxoy I was thinking this but seems to take up 2/3 lines of code, I wanted to try keep it small and simple if possible

Comment: so could u please be so kind and provide us with a snippet of your code

Comment: @inxoy I've provided a snippet, thanks

Comment: and whats wrong with it?  only that it is not as short as in py?

Comment: You just answered your question?

Comment: @inxoy agreed, and with it being ugly & chunky, I was wondering if theirs an alternative which makes it much cleaner

Comment: @Curtis Take a look at `array_map`

Comment: List comprehensions are a spiffy perk of Python.

Answer (score 1):

This construction is a python syntax sugar for `map`. Php has built-in function `array_map`:

```
$a = array_map(function($item) { return $item[‘key’]; }, $items);
```